# App crashes but still says "running..." in the debugger console

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, crash

It's a scroll view based app with paging, that plays a sound when each page is scrolled to.  For some reason it will randomly crash mid-scroll sometimes, but the debugger doesn't say it crashed.  It still says "GDB: Running..."  Any general advice on how to narrow the problem down?  `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` does finish (checked with NSLogs), and then it just freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to interrupt with `^C` in the terminal/debugger window, then `bt` to see where it was running/what it was doing.  If it's not clear enough where it's spinning, try setting breakpoints and then `cont`ing.